# Group question: only one element $x$ with order $n>1$, then $x\in Z(G)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I just tried to solve this question on a exam:

> Let $G$ be a group with only one element $x$ of order $n$, $n$ natural. Show that $x\in Z(G)$. (I'm using multiplicative notation)

$Z(G)$ is the subset of G such that every element of $Z(G)$ commutes with every element of G (called the Center of G).

I tried to do it like this: Suppose that x does not commute with at least one $g\in G$. Then $xg\neq gx\rightarrow x\neq gxg^{-1}$. Then,

$x^n\neq (g x g^{-1})^n=g x g^{-1}g x g^{-1}...g x g^{-1}=xx...x=gx^ng^{-1}=1$

Notice that $g x g^{-1}$ cannot have an order $n < m$ because its order depends exclusively of the order of $x$, which is $n$.

That means that there are two distinct elements in $G$ with order $n$, which is a contradiction.

Can someone tell me if it was done correctly?

Comment: When you made (gxg-1)^n the result is g(x^n)g-1 and it is equal to 1.

Comment: Yes, that's correct... I hope its just a minor mistake :D, Just edited.

Comment: @GustavoMarra — Even if it is not needed, note that if there is exactly one element of order n in G, then n is 1 or 2.

Comment: Some people tried to do it using this fact, but they couldn't conclude that the thesis was true through this.

Comment: I agree, this fact is not useful in the proof. But it is interesting to note the false generality of the statement.

Comment: Yes! I was startled when someone told me about this fact... made me think my solution was wrong :)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

you should know that for any $g\in G$ the order of $g^{-1}xg$ equal with order of x so for any $g\in G$ $g^{-1}xg=x$ then we have $x\in Z(G)$

Comment: That's, in essence, what I had  to show.