# If a group has only one element $a$ of order $n$, then $a$ belongs to $Z (G)$ and $n=2$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, cyclic-groups

I understand that $a \in Z (G)$ by this proof: [Group question: only one element $x$ with order $n>1$, then $x\in Z(G)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/130892/group-question-only-one-element-x-with-order-n1-then-x-in-zg)
But I don't understand why $n$ must be equal to $2$?

Comment: $\langle a\rangle$ is cyclic with $\varphi(n)$ generators.

Comment: sorry, can you elaborate?

Comment: I rolled back the spurious edits.

Comment: I do not think this question is absurd,just an elementary question which should be welcome.Thus,I upvoted to erase down vote.

Comment: @mesel Do you also find it fine that the asker apparently does not feel like spending even a minute thinking about a hint before asking for an elaboration?

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft: Yeah,but it is in comment not in question which should be evaluated speratly in my opinion.

Comment: @mesel I don't see why.

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft: ok,no problem.

Comment: I do apologize for not thinking harder, was really late at night and really frustrated with the question
Thank you for helping!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint** What is the order of $a^{-1}$?

Comment: order of a^-1 is equal to order of a

Comment: @Rod So $a$ and $a^{-1}$ are two distinct elements of order $n$ unless $a=a^{-1}$.

Answer (score 1):

It is proved that $O(a)=O(a^{-1})$ and we know a is the only element of order n
so $a=a^{-1}$
We multiply both sides by $a$ : $$a^{2}=e$$
then we know $$o(a) | 2$$

now $o(a)$ can be only 1 or 2

so proof $t=2$ is the smallest number that $a^{t}=e$